# I need the jquery to reach this nested div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out how to reach a nested div from the outer most element. Here is the html:

```
<li id="slide1">
<div id="video-container">
<div id=video-holder><div id="thumbnail"></div></div>
<div id=video-title></div>
<div id=video-desc></div>
</div>
</li>
```

I need jquery that will reach the id thumbnail from the starting id of the slide1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use find to get the descendant.

```
$("#slide1").find("#thumbnail")
```

Basically since it is id you can just do: as id is supposed to be unique no matter where it appears.

```
$("#thumbnail");
```

For your scenario you want to use startswith selector to select the dynamic id starts with `video_fake` and in the 5th 
slide.

```
$('#slide5fake').find('[id^=video_fake]').attr('id', 'newId')
```

Comment: The problem is the id is dynamic, sorry for not including that

Comment: @user2067005 only this id is dynamic?

Comment: How about the id `video-holder`?

Comment: yes, the thumbnail id is specific the the video id in my database, so video22, video34, video19, etc

Comment: So that is also dynamic...? Is it always going to be the second element under slide1?

Comment: $("#slide1").find("#video-holder").children().attr('id');. This work for me.

Comment: Is there a better way to do it other then using children?

Comment: I thought you said video-holder is dynamic. You could do `$("#slide1").find("#video-holder > div").attr(id)`

Comment: Ok then `$('#video-holder').find('div').attr('id')`. You are not duplicating the id are you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31792/discussion-between-user2067005-and-psl)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#slide1").find("#thumbnail")
```

Comment: Redundant. You could use `$("#thumbnail")` but I suspect that's not the real solution either

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<li id="slide1">
<div id="video-container">
<div id=video-holder><div class="thumbnail"></div></div>
<div id=video-title></div>
<div id=video-desc></div>
<div id="video-container">
<div id=video-holder><div class="thumbnail"></div></div>
<div id=video-title></div>
<div id=video-desc></div>
</div>
</li>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('#slide1').find('.thumbnail').each(function(){ });//you can get here two thumbnail
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#thumbnail")
```

will find the thumbnail directly, but I suspect the id for your thumbnail will be repeated down the page, so you really need to be searchind for a class.

```
$("#slide1.thumbnail")
```

will do that if you change this line

```
<div id=video-holder><div id="thumbnail"></div></div>
```

to this

```
<div id=video-holder><div class="thumbnail"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case there are more "thumbnails" on your page, it would be better to give it a class. Ids should be unique.

In your given case, it would be sufficient to get it by ID

```
document.getElementById("#thumbnail")
```

If you gave it a class

```
document.querySelector("#slide1 .thumbnail")
```

would get you the element.

In jQuery the equivalent would be:

```
$("#slide1").find(".thumbnail");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this...

Single selector:

```
$('#slide1 #thumbnail');
```

If you already have the slide element:

```
var slide = document.getElementById("slide1");

// and then:
$('#thumbnail', slide);
```

Doing a .find() on the #slide1 element

```
$("slide1").find("#thumbnail");
```

But since you're using an ID it doesn't make sense to do anything else but finding that single ID, since you shouldn't have more than one element on a page with the same ID

```
$("#thumbnail");
```

There are probably more ways.. and what the best method is depends a lot on what you're doing and what the context is...

Good luck